# Image Manipulation Library / API for Modifying Faces

Tags: .net, c++, python, c

I'm looking for an image manipulation library, preferably in .NET, that makes it easy to recognize and manipulate faces in images. Is there a library out there that does this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) (Open Source Computer Vision), which is a is a library of programming functions for real time computer vision.

I'm not familiar with it, so I don't know if it will make "easy to recognize and manipulate faces in images", but you can give it a look. It's not in .Net, but you tagged your question with C++ and Python, and it works with those.

Comment: Doesn't need to be in .NET - for something this specialized, I'll take it in whatever language I can ;)